# Difference between NSLog and DLog

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, logging, nslog

Can anyone tell me what the difference is between `NSLog` and `DLog`?

I found about this DLog when I was looking over this project code: http://code.google.com/p/iphone-socks-proxy/

Comment: What is DLog out of curiosity?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=DLog+vs+NSLog 989,000 results.

Comment: [The Evolution of a Replacement for NSLog](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/debugging/the-evolution-of-a-replacement-for-nslog)

Comment: @CodaFi and this is the top hit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`NSLog` is a function that's built into the Foundation framework that Apple provides. I've never heard of `DLog`, so I assume that it's a non-standard function that's implemented by the code you're looking at.

Comment: `DLog` stands for 'Debug Log' (I'm assuming) and is usually a macro that evaluates to nothing if the `DEBUG` environment flag is turned off - mostly in shipping apps.

Comment: @Kurt: Even I thought that in first place but I could not find anything in that project. And Here is the project link which I am looking at: http://code.google.com/p/iphone-socks-proxy/

Comment: It's defined in [SocksProxy_Prefix.pch](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-socks-proxy/source/browse/trunk/SocksProxy_Prefix.pch).

Answer (score 70):

DLog is a commonly used "Debug NSLog" alternative (just Google for it)

Here is a complete set of Log #define directives (including **ULog**, a **UIAlertView** based Logging feature)

```
// DLog will output like NSLog only when the DEBUG variable is set

#ifdef DEBUG
#   define DLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#else
#   define DLog(...)
#endif

// ALog will always output like NSLog

#define ALog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);

// ULog will show the UIAlertView only when the DEBUG variable is set 

#ifdef DEBUG
#   define ULog(fmt, ...)  { UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s\n [Line %d] ", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__] message:[NSString stringWithFormat:fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__]  delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil]; [alert show]; }
#else
#   define ULog(...)
#endif
```

Just put them in your precompile header (.pch) file.

(source: http://overbythere.co.uk/blog/2012/01/alternatives-nslog)

Comment: Hello my project don't have a PCH file. So where to put it?

Comment: @Rocotilos maybe you are using swift (so, no pch file..)

Comment: Actually I am using ObjC. Xcode 7.3.1. Project is single view and storyboard mode. If no PCH, do u know where to put this code to use them?

Comment: @Rocotilos create your pch as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158648/why-isnt-projectname-prefix-pch-created-automatically-in-xcode-6

Comment: Pascal, thanks that clarifies it nicely. I think it is weird to put in PCH too. Each project should have its own headers. Or maybe one can make static library and use that for most projects.

Answer (score 13):

DLog is a macro meant to conditionalize the behavior of `NSLog()` in debug and release builds.  For release builds it will print nothing.  `NSLog()` is meant to print format strings to the console.

Here is its definition for reference:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#    define DLog(...) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#    define DLog(...) /* */
#endif
#define ALog(...) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: That's not true. `NSLog` isn't meant to be used to print string literals to console - for that, you can use `printf` (or `fputs`) and friends if you'd like. The point of `NSLog` is to print useful and valid information to the system log.

Answer (score 8):

*Hi,
Below the macro cmd for NSLOG replacement file format and also below i mentioned undef Macro as well as*

**Definition:**

```
#define _LOG_TO_CONSOLE_ //#undef _LOG_TO_CONSOLE_
#ifdef _LOG_TO_CONSOLE_
#define DLog(format, ...) NSLog(format, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define DLog(format, ...)
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I think an important difference between NSLog and DLog is that NSLog lags the execution of the program (imagine forgetting to remove all NSLog calls in production/publishing), so for debug purposes DLog should be used.