# How to see an object that is receiving messages after being deallocated

Tags: iphone, xcode, crash, release, dealloc

I am getting below error, but want more specific information like line number, class_name, method_name etc.

`-[__NSArrayM release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x72ab440`

In other words, decrypt memory address 0x72ab440?

Any help?

Comment: Doesn't keeping breakpoints help in debugging code?

Answer (score 0):

You could use DLog, but then you'd already know where the problem was...

[Difference between NSLog and DLog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659763/difference-between-nslog-and-dlog)

Answer (score 0):

Go to `XCode -> Preferences -> Text Editing` and modify the following..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode finder window select the Xcode preferences and then select the text editing and finally select the check mark options in line numbers.
XCode>Preference>Text Editing>Line numbers(select the check mark)

Answer (score 0):

It's not the line number you are looking for, so the answers you are getting about how to display the line number are barking up the wrong tree.

What you are asking for is a way of knowing which objects are being sent messages, even though they have been deallocated.

The way to do that is by turning on NSZombies.

You can do it within Xcode in the Scheme settings

[image]

Make sure you only have this for debug builds, btw.

And with this option turned on, you'll get a more informative indication of what object is being messaged and where from.